# Generate Access Token from Another Microservice

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, bearer-token, java-17

I would like to hear your insights regarding my dilemma that made me stuck for days.

Here's the issue:

I have an adapter class called "RiderAvailClientAdapter" which implements my connection to another microservice called RAVA.

The problem is I can't connect to the said service since it has a security token.

Now I created an implementation that would solve the issue.
Solution is that I implemented a generateAuthToken method in my "AuthClientAdapter" that will handle the generation of token coming from another microservice called AUTH (Which the service that handles all of the security)

Issue:
It can't generate the said token from my client api but my username and password as request body are being read within the app. I tested the same username and password in postman for the api I wanted to connect to and it worked. In short, it works in POSTMAN but NOT within my app.

FF are the codes

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RiderAvailClientAdapter implements RiderAvailabilityRESTClientPort {
            
 private final RiderAvailClientProxy riderAvailClientProxy;
            
 private final AuthClientAdapter authClientAdapter;
            
 @Override
 public RiderAvailabilityStatusDto getRiderStatus(String riderNumber) {
 String accessToken = authClientAdapter.getAccessToken();
 return riderAvailClientProxy.getRiderStatus(riderNumber, "Bearer " + accessToken);
  }
}



@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthClientAdapter implements AuthClientPort {

   private final AuthClientProxy authClientProxy;

   private final AuthServiceConfiguration authServiceConfiguration;

   private String accessToken;


    /**
     * 240000 = 4 min: will generate new token after each 4min.
     */
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 240000)
    public void generateAuthToken() {
        log.info("Generating access token...");
        LoginRequestDto loginRequest = new LoginRequestDto();
        loginRequest.setUsername(authServiceConfiguration.getUsername());
        loginRequest.setPassword(authServiceConfiguration.getPassword());
        try {
            LoginResponseDto loginResponseDTO = authClientProxy.login(loginRequest);
            accessToken = loginResponseDTO.getAccessToken();
            log.info("access token generated successfully...");
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            log.error("Error while generating access token : ", e);
        }
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what is an exactly a problem. Does you service return anything or it throw error? Are you sure that your job was executed at all?

Comment: It executed a 500 Internel server error. Upon debugging,  it says that the getAccessToken is null, meaning it couldn't get the token from the login api of the other microservice (Auth Service) i'm connecting to. However if I test the same username and pass via the api (of the Auth service it allows me to get in the service including the other one called RAVA, which means that there is no issues on the credentials part). Now, I am so lost. 

Comment: You need to check logs of your Auth Service, to check does request reach service and what did cause issue to produce 500 error?

Comment: I haven't tried checking the logs on my auth service as I was so occupied checking/debugging my service. This is such a great advise to point out. I will check on this tomorrow and will give you an update. Thank you so much kind soul!

Comment: Hi This is resolved. In the issue above I failed to call the generateAuthToken() method under my getAccesToken() method the reason why it results to null. Thanks.